# How to load output of a PHP Script into another script variable without file_get_contents()

Tags: php

I really need help of you. What i want is it that i want to load output of a PHP Script into  another PHP script variable. And then echo it.

```
 print "<ul>";
    for($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($govtJobsRslt);$i++){
    $job = mysqli_fetch_array($govtJobsRslt);
    $jobId = $job[0];
    $jobTitle = $job[1];
    $jobEmployer = $job[2];
    $jobVacancies = $job[3];
    $jobPage = $job[4];       
    $query2 = "SELECT employer_shortname, employer_city FROM employer WHERE employer_id               = $jobEmployer";
   $empDtlRslt = mysqli_query($link, $query2);
   if($empDtlRslt){                        
           $empDtls = mysqli_fetch_array($empDtlRslt);
           $empShortName = $empDtls[0];
           $empCity = $empDtls[1];                 
            **$new1 = file_get_contents("http://url/summaryProvider2.phpjobId=".$jobId);**
           print "<li id=\"lst$jobId\" class=\"qs\"><a href=\"/govtjobs/$jobPage\">".$empShortName." ".$empCity."-".$jobTitle."-".$jobVacancies." Posts</a> </li><div id=\"sum$jobId\" class=\"jobSummary\">".$new1."</div>";
```

I want to replace file_get_contents() method because this is not working on web server becasue it is disabled for security reasons.

Please tell me the other way that how can i do that???
Is it possible somehow using include() method???

Guys please help soon...

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.+

Comment: But its a SELECT only statement than how is it vulnerable because no input is possible it is for presentation only

Comment: What is disabled? Is the function `file_get_contents()` disabled? (unlikely, nasty if so), is `allow_url_fopen` disabled (more likely)? If that is the case, [is the curl extension available](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)? If curl is available, use that.

Comment: I removed allow_url_fopen from disable list but the behavior did not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use fopen just open it as a regular text file but that is not better than file_get_contents.
You can also have your web server treat this file as a non php file, and then it will just spill the contents to whoever requests it so then you can use curl to the local machine to get it.